# SVN: Vendor branches + patching + history?

Tags: svn, version-control, external, patch, vendor-branch

We have a rather large library that we need to periodically import (and then patch) to our code base.

The SVN Book seems to reccomend a "vendor branch" scheme where we keep our patched version of the "vendor drops".   This would work, except that the vendor also uses SVN and gives us read access to their reop.

It would be great to have access to history of the vendor files when we need to update our patches.

So my question is:

Is there a way to have a patched "vendor branch" that also somehow keeps access to the history for the vendor files?

(I've seen mention of svn:external folders, but I'm not sure I really understand the full ramifications in terms of pegging a revision, nor how exactly we would maintain our own patches against that.)

What is the correct route to take here?   (FWIW, the vendor releases once a month. We intend to pull updates about once/twice a year.)

Thanks

Comment: It is not the answer you expected, but (even though I really like svn) if you expect to work with branches intensively, then SVN could be not a good decision for you. Instead of SVN i propose you to look at Mercurial or GIT Mercurial is more simple, i use it for my private projects, and GIT is more powerful.

Comment: @zerkms  Yeah, SVN is a "business requirement", sadly.  No choice in the matter.

Comment: @zerkms, branching works just fine in Subversion.  You just have to know how to use the tools and have firm grasp of version control techniques and methodologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the rub, you want the vendor's source along with history, but you also apply your patch to the vendor's source.  Getting their source with history is easy.  Getting their source with history and then applying your patches and continually do this, that is tough.

Now assuming you don't place the vendor's source directory into your source (meaning you build the two projects separately), you have couple of options if you keep the two source in separate repositories.

If you wanted the vendors source along with history, you can set up an svnsync to the vendors repository and pull their changes on a regular interval.  Svnsync is a wonderfull way to get something remotely as a local copy with a complete set of history.  But the one caveat to svnsync is that is the repository becomes read-only.  So you cannot apply the patch to their source.

Now, since you do this only once or twice a year, you could go through the process of pulling down a new copy of their repository using svnsync.  Break the sync and make your copy of the vendor's repo writable and then apply your patches.

The other option would be have the vendor do a dump of their repo and send it to you.  Then you would load that dump into your own repository and make read/write.

With either option, you'll have to reapply your patches to your copy of the vendor's repository every time you go through this process.  At least you only do this once or twice a year.

Now, if you have to have their source in your source, still do the above, but use the svn:external like you noted in your question.  You'll still need to apply any patches you need to make to the vendor's source to your copy of the vendor's repository.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by svn:externals?  Can I maintain a patched-branch in my own repo based an on svn:external?

Comment: Clarification of svn:externals usage: You would have the vendor's source in it's own repository along with your specific patches to the vendor source.  If your project (in it's own repository) also compiles the patched vendor's source along with it's own source, using svn:externals would be the best solution for that.  This is because you indicated that you periodically pull the newer versions of the vendors source.  That would allow you to swap out the vendor source easier.

Comment: @nonot1: I wouldn't treat the vendor source as a branch, but a separate project stored in it's own repository.  This would make it easier to automate the refresh of the vendor source.  But having the vendor source in a separate repository effectively acts like a branch that you can apply your own patches to.  From there you can then use the svn:externals to include it your projects source (if need be).